# Who else was at Hawkman's funeral besides the five speaking characters?

Tags: dc, tv, superman, smallville

I just re-watched the episode "Icarus" of *Smallville*, where "Deathstroke" kills Hawkman, and some of the remaining "Justice League" takes him to Egypt and buries him next to Shayera. Something that bothered me was during the funeral procession itself.

You can see the five main characters carrying the coffin itself, in costume: Black Canary, Stargirl, Green Arrow, Lois and Clark. But there are at least three more people walking behind the casket that I cannot identify. Also, at the end, after the VRA team gasses the entire room and knocks all of the heroes out, there appears to be at least one unidentified, unconscious body lying between a pair of stone blocks. The only other "Justice League" members I know of at the time would be Impulse and Aquaman, and the first person in line *looks like* a female dressed in a red hooded outfit, which doesn't fit anyone else I know.

In the subsequent episode, while the heroes are still being held in the VRA facility, Black Canary makes a brief reference to Aquaman also being present, but he is never seen on-screen and none of the three mystery people appeared to be dressed as Aquaman.

Is there any indication who those three were, or is anyone able to identify them (perhaps via their outfits)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it says on the [Smallville Wiki](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Icarus#Cameo_Roles) they were:

> John Jones/Martian Manhunter
>   Bart Allen/Impulse
>   Arthur Curry/Aquaman
>   Zatanna Zatara
>   Victor Stone/Cyborg

Comment: Hm. I'm always leery about taking Smallville Wiki's word for anything but I guess there's no more definitive answer in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield no problem ^_^

Comment: oddly, I just rewatched the episode and I cannot see any place where *five* extra characters appear on-screen. It took single-stepping my DVR just to see the three extras. I'm now REALLY curious where the wiki information came from :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see enough if you look closely that the ones mentioned by @TheDoctor are there.  I doubt it was the actual actors who usually portray them, but given their clothing (especially the colors), there's little doubt in my mind who the attendees are.